# K-Means Clustering too crowded

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I have written a simple python code that opens a csv files and then clusters the values of one column. There around 10k rows

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')

data.head()

feature_names = ['numbers_col']
X = np.asarray(data[feature_names])

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

labels = KMeans(5, random_state=10).fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 0], c=labels,
            s=50, cmap='rainbow');
```

This is how the result looks like

[image]

The result doesn't look that good it looks all liner and the clusters are shown just like dots.

I am asking for some advice so my output would look more  towards what a normal K-Means output looks like: Example

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure looks exactly how it should.

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 0], c=labels, s=50, cmap='rainbow');
```

You are plotting the a value again itself, in two dimensions it will give you a line of the form **y = x**
Check what you want to plot, if you have only one feature it doesn't mean that the K-Means wouldn't work, you will have a clustering, but the plot its correct.

Comment: marked it answred. I wanted to ask if there is a way to be able to extract the values of the cluster on the right most corner ( first graph blue color cluster) I want to learn

Comment: Yes.
The sklearn kmeans returns all lables in the object you created.
You name it labels (I will advise you to name cluster or something, labels acn be   misleading a bit).
Check lables.labels_ attribute, you can map the training sample by the position (first in labels_ is first in you training set and so on).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just clustering one column it can only look at the relative distance between the values in *that* column and will always be linear on any chart as it is only clustering one dimension.

To get a result like the second image you have posted would require to cluster across two  columns (in the case above you have scale_age on the x axis and scale_wander on the y axis).

Answer (score 1):

I would say the KMeans algo is doing exactly what it's supposed to do.  I would be much more surprised if it DIDN'T do what you told it to do.  I was also skeptical the first time I saw plots of my own KMeans calculations.  Maybe plotting the data in a 3D chart would be more useful/practical.  Here is some sample code that you should be able to adapt to your specific scenario.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
color = sns.color_palette()
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noahgift/real_estate_ml/master/data/Zip_Zhvi_SingleFamilyResidence_2018.csv")
df.head()

for col in df.columns: 
    print(col) 


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
newdf = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)

newdf = newdf.fillna(0)

pca_ = PCA(n_components=3)
X_Demo_fit_pca = pca_.fit_transform(newdf)

kmeans_PCA = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init='k-means++', max_iter= 300, n_init= 10, random_state= 3)

y_kmeans_PCA = kmeans_PCA.fit_predict(X_Demo_fit_pca)
y_kmeans_PCA

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X_Demo_fit_pca[:,0],X_Demo_fit_pca[:,1],X_Demo_fit_pca[:,2], 
            c=y_kmeans_PCA, cmap='viridis',
            edgecolor='k', s=40, alpha = 0.5)


ax.set_title("First three PCA directions")
ax.set_xlabel("Educational_Degree")
ax.set_ylabel("Gross_Monthly_Salary")
ax.set_zlabel("Claim_Rate")
ax.dist = 10
```

[image]

In your case, it would be something like:

```
`X[:,0],X[:,1],X[:,2],c=labels`
```

Also, don't forget this line:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

Try that and see how you get along.

FYI...if I did a generic 2D plot, like yours, with the data from the sample I showed above, I would get this as a result.

```
plt.scatter(X_Demo_fit_pca[:, 0], X_Demo_fit_pca[:, 0], c=y_kmeans_PCA, s=50, cmap='rainbow');
```

[image]